# Amending a lightswitch field value inside a matrix, from a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, matrix, lightswitch

I have a plugin which is used to send a notification email when certain events happen.

I need to watch the contents of a Matrix field attached to a User, and when a Lightswitch field inside the Matrix is 'on', flip another Lightswitch field on the same matrix block. Here's the simplified code I have so far:

```
craft()->on('users.onBeforeSaveUser', function(Event $event) {
    foreach ($user->getContent()->myMatrixField as $matrixBlock) {
        if($matrixBlock->firstLightswitch){
            $matrixBlock->secondLightswitch = '1';
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error though:

> Property “Craft\MatrixBlockModel.secondLightswitch” is not defined

It's very definitely defined. I presume I'm trying to set the field incorrectly, but can't find out how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do:

```
$matrixBlock->getContent()->setAttribute('secondLightswitch', '1');
```

You can only **get** attributes via magic methods but you can't **set** them

Comment: Thanks Robin - now I need to read up about "magic methods".